# Not able to see tab in app navigation menu despite having permission

Tags: apex, custom-object, tab-settings

I am facing an issue regarding a **custom tab** which does not appear in an app even though it seems like there would be no technical reason for that. I have checked the following aspects in the org:

- I am system admin
- I have access to that custom tab
- the custom tab is
  included in the app I am working with
- I have access to the object
- the
  app is created in Classic but I am using it in Lightning as well. But
  even if I switch to Classic I cannot see that tab. For now I would not like to upgrade it to become a Lightning App.

Can you please help me?

Comment: `Check 1:` Is the menu item hidden in the overflow chevron? `Check 2:` See the tab visibility in your profile. If both these checks pass, please go to the app in APP MENU, edit the application in which you are in and make sure that it is available there. Then check `Overwrite Users' Personal Custom App Customizations` and Save and let us know the results.

Comment: Hi @manjit5190! I have checked all of that before asking this question. The tab does not appear at all. Not in the app navigation menu and not under the "More" tab. Besides, for the check 2 I did all of that and the tab is not visible.

Comment: Is the object for tab in a managed package or the one that you have created? Also can you save it after selecting the overwrite checkbox?

Comment: @manjit5190 the object is created by other user some time ago and does not belong to a managed package.

Comment: I have checked once again and there was a probem on the profile level. The tab visibility was the cause. Thanks!

Comment: Great! that it was resolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check 1: Is the menu item hidden in the overflow chevron?

Check 2: See the tab visibility in your profile.

If both these checks pass, please go to the app in APP MENU, edit the application in which you are in and make sure that it is available there. Then check Overwrite Users' Personal Custom App Customizations and Save and let us know the results.

Comment: Hi @manjit5190! As I said above, the tab visibility in profile was set up wrong. So this was the solution. Thank you!